# How to make a map with a vector inside?

Tags: c++, vector

I would to make a map with a vector inside it, but I never made that and I'm new to `C++`.
I tried this way but I have an error, `expected expression` at the end.

```
void NcursesGraph::addDrawableElement(const std::string &object_name, const std::string &object_filepath)
{
    _object.push_back(object_filepath);
    _elem.insert(std::pair<const std::string &, std::vector<const std::string &>>(object_name, _object>));
}
```

and here are the definition in my `.hpp`:

```cpp
std::map<const std::string &, std::vector<const std::string &>> _elem;
std::vector<const std::string &> _object;
```

Comment: Can you show the definition of _elem?

Comment: Impossible to say what's the correct code without knowing the declarations of `_elem` and `_object`. But I would try `_elem.insert(std::make_pair(object_name, _object));`

Comment: Also, an simple error in your code, `_object>` should be just `_object`.

Comment: You can’t have a vector of references.

Comment: please add [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question.

Comment: I modified my post

Comment: @Thomas_Vcheck: Can you please add the exact error message? BTW, here's a small working code snippet for your use-case: https://godbolt.org/z/ozcA5-. You're using `const std::string&` as type in `std::vector` and key in `std::map`. Please refer to the documentation for the requirements for the construction of respective containers ([`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map)). Tip: You should use the [type aliases](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) to improve the readability.